# How to convert string with signed integer value to signed integer?

Tags: python, type-conversion

I'm using int(myString), myString = "-1" and I get error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"-1"'
```

Comment: What's your Python version, 2.7 does `int("-1")` with no problem. Looks like your number is double quoted. Was able to reproduce it by `int('"-1"')`

Comment: Why define the `myString` after the `conversion`? Can you post all you code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The string contains quotes, i.e.

```
s = '"-1"'
```

You need to get rid of the quotes, something like

```
s = '"-1"'
int(s.replace('"', ''))
```

should do the trick.

Comment: thanks, I'm modifying someones code so it wasn't that easy to notice, in fact I just guessed that there should be "-1" but there wasn't, and I have 1 hour of python programming experience ;)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you're string doesent look like `"'-1'"` and not `"-1"`

```
a = "'-1'"
print int(a)
>>> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"-1"'

a = "-1"
print int(a)
>>> -1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [2]: int(eval('"-1"'))
Out[2]: -1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> int("-1")
-1

>>> int('"-1"')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    int('"-1"')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"-1"'

>>> '"-1"'.strip('\"')
'-1'
```

Answer (score 1):

[str.strip](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method accepts characters. You can use it to get rid of surrounding quotes:

```
>>> int('"-1"'.strip('"'))
-1
>>>
```